Smoothness of expectation of a piecewise function
Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are piecewise smooth functions. For simplicity, we can assume that $f(x)$ has $m$ pieces, and $g(x):=\max_{i=1,2,\ldots, I}\left\{k_i~ x+b_i\right\}$.
I have two questions:

Is $h(x):=\mathbb{E}_W[g(Wx)]$ a smooth function instead of a piecewise function? Here, $W$ is a continuous random variable.
If Question 1 is true, then can I conclude that $h(f(x))$ has exactly $m$ pieces as $f(x)$, and they have exactly the same breakpoints?

My intuition behind Question 1: Integration can be viewed as summation. Suppose W is discrete, and can take 100 values, then $\mathbb{E}_W[g(Wx)]$ should have 100*I pieces. Now that $W$ is continuous, it can take infinitely many values, so the true $\mathbb{E}_W[g(Wx)]$ should have infinitely many pieces, effectively a smooth function. But  how to properly prove it?
My intuition behind Question 2: If my above intuition is true and $h(x)=\mathbb{E}_W[g(Wx)]$ indeed is a smooth function, then by plugging $f(x)$ into $h(x)$, it should give me a piecewise function that has the same number of pieces and the same breakpoints as $f(x)$.

The function $h(x)$ need not be smooth. Consider $g(x) = |x| = \max{x, -x}$ and let $W$ be any continuous random variable. Then, $h(x) = \mathbb{E}_W[|Wx|] = |x| \cdot \mathbb{E}[|W|] = c |x|$, where $c$ is some non-negative numerical constant. The function $h(x)$ is clearly non-smooth at $x = 0$.

@sudeep5221 Thanks for the counterexample. In this case, is there any way that we can prove the opposite: h(x) is always piecewise linear just like g(x)?

I don't think that holds either. Take $g(x) = |x - 0.5|$ and $W$ to be uniform random variable over $[0,1]$. If my computation is correct, $h(x)$ is smooth but it's derivative is not. I think you can show that whenever $b_i \neq 0$, then $h(x)$ will be smooth.
